# Site.CreateExternalUser vs directly inserting user object in apex

Tags: experience-cloud

What is the best practice of creating community users?
Is it by using Site.createExternalUser api or directly inserting user object?

Comment: `Site.createExternalUser` has a myriad of issues, it's only good in very few happy path scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a user and a contact in the same transaction is not allowed. You end up with a `MIXED_DML` exception. Workarounds exist, but are not ideal. If you use `Site.createExternalUser`, it will create the user and contact (if necessary) all in one step. In addition, you can also set their default password (or any supplied password) at once, which can also be used with `Site.validatePassword` to make sure the passwords match and match the org's password policies. In other words, you should not be using a standard DML operation to create external community users. The Site method is the recommended approach.

Comment: So what if I want to relate the community user to an existing contact. And the matching contact is identified using a custom text field . In that scenario whether i can use Site.CreateExternalUser?

Comment: @LoneWolf777 The createExternalUser method matches strictly by email, not a custom field. If you already have the custom data you're looking for, it should be easy to get the email for the contact from there.